# Angular main.js does not work. Is it supposed to be linked in some way?

Tags: javascript, html

When running the project with ng serve, javascript does not have any effect. Even console.log() is not working. Css styles are perfectly fine. When I check all the linked scripts it shows that main.js is fine.
For example, here is app.component.html:

```
<button class="btn">Click</button>
```

And here is main.js

```
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn")

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("Text") 
})
```

Clearly it is supposed to print 'Text', but it does not respond and do anything. It works normally on a separate html file, so apparantly the code is not the problem.

Comment: have you defined `btn`? this is clearly a mistake.

Comment: How i that angular code ?

Comment: You have to get the element using selectors in JS and then you should apply the listeners, The answer does provide you the solution for it. Incase you want to use class, you can still do it

Answer (score 1):

btn is a class in your example. You might want to get it with an id.

for example:

HTML

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

JS

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("Text") 
})
```